# SendMessage, When To Use KEYDOWN, SYSKEYDOWN, etc?

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I am writing an application that sends keystrokes to another application using `SendMessage`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
```

I have been experimenting with the various arguments and I have noticed that, depending on which keystroke I am sending, I have to pass in different arguments to the parameter `int Msg`.

For example, I have the following defined as possible values for `Msg`.

```
private static ushort WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
private static ushort WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
private static ushort WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
```

and the following test keys that are passed in to the 3rd parameter `wParam`:

```
private static ushort VK_F1 = 0x70;
private static ushort VK_A = 0x41;
private static ushort VK_TAB = 0x09;
```

When I want to send the <kbd>F1</kbd> key (`VK_F1`) it only works whenever is use `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, when I want to send the <kbd>A</kbd> key it only works when I use `WM_CHAR`, and when I want to send the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key it only works when I use `WM_KEYDOWN`.

My question is: is there some documentation out there that tells me when to use `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, etc. based on what key that is being sent? Or perhaps I am doing it wrong and there is one consistent method that works for any key?

Comment: why not use SendInput and let the OS worry about the messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft explains the difference between these WM messages here [Keyboard Input (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`WM_SYSKEYDOWN` simulates system commands like <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> used to switch windows.

`WM_CHAR` simulates user input like input in a text box for instance.

`WM_KEYDOWN` is usually used together with `WM_KEYUP`. See [WM_KEYDOWN message (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Most probably you will want to use `WM_CHAR`.