# send keydown and keyup separately

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am currently using this code:

```
else if (y2 > 0 && x2 < 0) {
  SendKeys.SendWait("wa");
  completion = completion + 0.1;
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
  if (completion > y2) {
    break;
  }
}
```

However, instead of doing `SendKeys.SendWait`, I would like to only press those down, instead of downupdownup.

Answer (score 1):

From this Stackoverflow question, [SendMessage, When To Use KEYDOWN, SYSKEYDOWN, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514820/sendmessage-when-to-use-keydown-syskeydown-etc), it appears that the way to send key-down messages requires using the user32.dll library:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
```

The parameter, `Msg`, has an option that allows the sending of KeyDown events:

```
private static ushort WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
```

If you have the flexibility to implement your solution in other environments outside of .NET, [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) offers a rich set of functionality for sending input.